# Is it correct to say that; an object moving at a constant velocity is moving in a straight line?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, reference-frames

I think it is correct because:
v = displacement/time, if the direction changes, the displacement changes so the velocity is not constant anymore.
Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: The second paragraph here explains nicely: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity

Comment: That will depend on the reference from where you are choosing the straight line. If you take a car moving on a straight road with constant speed , then yes it has constant velocity.  Observe the same car from Mars , its now performing a circular motion around earth

Comment: Thanks for the useful comment @NoahJ.Standerson, it's interesting! :D

Comment: No you an drive a circle path with constant velocity

Comment: @Eli, velocity is a vector, circular motion is accelerated motion, hence the velocity is not constant, the speed is constant in that case.

Comment: @Eli , Nope. You can drive in a circle with constant speed. No constant velocity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you are correct$^1$, to define an object's velocity we have to specify *in which direction* it is travelling and *how fast* - this defines a [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector) quantity. If we say the vector is unchanging, its length (the object's speed) and its orientation (which direction the object is travelling) must be constant in time which corresponds to an object travelling in a straight line at a constant speed.

$^1$ Ignoring complications for example the presence of a gravitational field.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Velocity has both magnitude as well as direction, so a constant velocity would imply constant direction as well. Constant *speed,* however doesn't necessarily mean straight-line motion (e.g. uniform motion along a circular path).

Answer (score 1):

The vector has direction and magnitude. If one of the two quantities changes, the vector changes.

And velocity is a vector. Therefore, the direction change leads to the velocity change which is the acceleration.

Comment: Can we say that a straight line is circumference of circle of infinite radius

Comment: @sheltonBenjamin Why do you need the definition?

Comment: Sorry its off topic but i still was wondering

Comment: @sheltonBenjamin You may open a new question including the reason why you consider the situation.

Comment: No i am not including this in the situation and question it is just a different question

Comment: If it's a different question, open the new one.